# If I only use two of the ports on my ISP router is it ideal or able to disable the unused ports?

Tags: networking, security

On a typical router from my ISP there are four lan ports and I only use two of them. My question is how could I disable the unused ports so that a it can't be just plugged into and used

Comment: it may be possible to prevent connection to those ports, but it depends on the router, and I actually doubt ISP routers would have the ability to configure those ports such that they are useless - not likely you can disable them, but you can configure ports on some routers so that they are effectively useless - again, highly unlikely on an ISP provided device

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: "_how could I disable the unused ports_" - do you have any particular reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: "how could I disable the unused ports so that a it can't be just plugged into and used?" – If you have a reason to do this, then you probably also need to physically secure the used ports, so nobody can plug the legitimate cables out, turning the used ports into unused ones they can use.

Answer (score 1):

The device from your ISP includes a router and also a 4 port switch. That explains the 4 LAN Network Ports.

There is no need to disable ports in any normal use.

A fairly expensive entry level commercial router allows you to turn ports off. My Cisco RV345 allows this. It is unlikely your ISP device offers this.

Unless your ISP device is in a public location, there is no danger. I assume from your post the ISP device belongs to the ISP so you cannot (legally) tamper with it.

Keep the device in a secure location and leave the ports as is.

Comment: Thanks For answering